# The member could not bex [sic] extracted from the cabinet file - MikTeX error

Tags: miktex

I am getting an error "The member could not bex extracted from the cabinet file" when installing MikTeX. please give some information regarding the cause of the error and how to solve it.

```
initializing setup service...
starting installer...
Loading package database...
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: C:\Users\AB\AppData\Local\Temp\mik99215
visiting repository C:\Users\AB\AppData\Local\Temp\mik99215...
repository type: local package repository
loading lightweight database...
lightweight database digest: 3b240316a510d51783808e34b23c0f33
going to install 10248 file(s) (174 package(s))
extracting files from ae.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amscls.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amsfonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amsmath.tar.lzma...
extracting files from avantgar.cab...
extracting files from babel.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-english.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-french.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-german.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-spanish.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bidi.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bookman.cab...
extracting files from carlisle.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cbcoptic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cm.tar.lzma...
extracting files from courier.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cyrillic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dehyph-exptl.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ec.tar.lzma...
extracting files from elhyphen.tar.lzma...
extracting files from enctex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from euenc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from eurosym.tar.lzma...
extracting files from float.cab...
extracting files from fontspec.tar.lzma...
extracting files from geometry.tar.lzma...
extracting files from graphics.tar.lzma...
extracting files from helvetic.cab...
extracting files from hyperref.tar.lzma...
extracting files from hyph-utf8.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ifxetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from jknappen.cab...
extracting files from latex-fonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lm.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ltxbase.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ltxmisc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lua-alt-getopt.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luainputenc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lualibs.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luamplib.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luaotfload.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luatexbase.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luatextra.tar.lzma...
extracting files from mflogo.tar.lzma...
extracting files from mflogo-font.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-arctrl-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibarts-bin.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibarts-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-biber-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex-base.cab...

An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Extractor\CabExtractor.cpp
  source line: 369
  message: The member could not bex extracted from the cabinet file.
  info: cabinetPath="C:\Users\AB\AppData\Local\Temp\mik99215\miktex-bibtex-base.cab", ret="2", member="texmf\doc\bibtex\btxbst.doc"
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Do you have enough disk space for the installation?